# Good algorithm for maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, statistics, economics

I have a problem. I need to estimate some statistics with GARCH/ARCH model. In Matlab I use something like this:

```
 spec = garchset('P', 1, 'Q', 1)
 [fit01,~,LogL01] =garchfit(spec, STAT);
```

so this returns three parameters of GARCH model with maximum likelihood.
But I really need to how which algorithm is used in **garchfit** , because I need to write a program which makes the same work in estimating parameters automatically.

My program works now very slow and sometimes not correct. 
So the questions are:

1. How get the code of garchfit or MLE in Matlab?
2. Does anyone know some good and fast algorithm on MLE?

(MLE = maximum likelihood estimation)

Comment: In Matlab, select any function name and press ctrl+D to open the source file

Answer (score 0):

To see the code (if possible) you can type `edit garchfit`.

From the [documentation of `garchfit`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/econ/garchfit.html) I have found some recommendations:

> garchfit will be removed in a future release. Use [estimate](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/econ/arima.estimate.html), [estimate](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/econ/garch.estimate.html),
>   [estimate](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/econ/egarch.estimate.html), or [estimate](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/econ/gjr.estimate.html) instead.

My guess is that you want to look into `garch.estimate`.